# How to save file in appdata

Tags: java, appdata

What's the path, I have to use to read and write a File which is in the appdata?

Can I use ImageIo or do I have to use something else. And can I use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter?

Answer (score 0):

`APPDATA` is an environment variable in Windows, so just build your paths including that directory, which you can get via `System.getenv("APPDATA")`.

So, for example

```
File imageFile = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\whatever\\picture.jpg");
```

Comment: That works fine. Or as alternative with NIO.2: Path path = Paths.get(System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\whatever\\picture.jpg")